# SELECT This or That but not both

Tags: mysql, subquery

I've got a very complicated query that's making my brain melt.

```
SELECT abunchOfStuff, r.xyz as netsell
FROM normalmtm n
JOIN mtmprogram m ON (
   m.mtmprogram = n.loanprogram
   AND m.investor = 'Xyzzy'
)
JOIN rates as r on (
    r.term >= '2012-01-01'
    AND r.investor = m.investor
    AND r.rate = n.rate
    AND r.program = m.basenormal
    AND r.clientcode = n.clientcode
)
LEFT OUTER JOIN mtmadjustments as ad ON (
    ad.loannumber = n.loannumber
    AND ad.investor = m.investor
)
WHERE n.loannumber = '12345678'
AND n.clientcode = 10
ORDER BY netsell DESC LIMIT 1
```

This is selecting the largest netsell from a bunch of them. Now, the tricky part I can't quite wrap my head around is that the rates table may or may not match on n.clientcode. If it doesn't match, I want to use the clientcode of 0, which is essentially a wildcard.

Right now I'm doing the clientcode specific query and if it returns nothing I'm doing this query again with clientcode = 0... and it seems like I could wrap those two things together somehow.

I looked at the EXISTS or NOT EXISTS subquery but I just couldn't figure out how to use it in this example and I'm not even sure it'd be appropriate.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: So if there is no record in rates with that client code, use the rate for that investor, rate and program and client code 0?

Comment: Seems like your title is misleading. You're not SELECTing one or the other, but comparing `r.clientcode` with either one value or another value, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT abunchOfStuff, ISNULL(r.xyz, r2.xyz) as netsell
FROM normalmtm n
JOIN mtmprogram m ON (
   m.mtmprogram = n.loanprogram
   AND m.investor = 'Xyzzy'
)
LEFT OUTER JOIN rates as r on (
    r.term >= '2012-01-01'
    AND r.investor = m.investor
    AND r.rate = n.rate
    AND r.program = m.basenormal
    AND r.clientcode = n.clientcode
)
LEFT OUTER JOIN rates as r2 on (
    r2.term >= '2012-01-01'
    AND r2.investor = m.investor
    AND r2.rate = n.rate
    AND r2.program = m.basenormal
    AND r2.clientcode = 0
)
LEFT OUTER JOIN mtmadjustments as ad ON (
    ad.loannumber = n.loannumber
    AND ad.investor = m.investor
)
WHERE n.loannumber = '12345678'
AND n.clientcode = 10
ORDER BY netsell DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Yes... I think this will work. Very nice! I'm not sure why I didn't think to use IFNULL, I use it in tons of other situations when I need a zero returned instead of a NULL.

Answer (score 0):

IFNULL() applied over clientcode in the join should do the trick

```
 AND r.clientcode = IFNULL(0, n.clientcode)
```

**EDIT**: Maybe I didn't understand your question fully... you say you want zero when they don't match, so initially I suggested an option when the field is null, so you get the zero to match the r.clientcode. IFNULL outputs the first value when the second is null or the second value when it's not null, just that.

But, if you need to do 1.) check if they match, 2.) if they do, join, 3.) if they don't, join with a zero value... you might need a subquery

```
 AND r.clientcode = ( IFNULL(0, select nn.clientcode FROM normalmtm nn where r.clientcode = nn.clientcode and nn.clientcode=n.clientcode) )
```

Something like that, maybe...

Comment: Sorry, I want the rates record for n.clientcode of 10, unless there's no match, then I want it to match n.clientcode = 0.